Añadir registros a un Tabla Access
Amigos necesito saber como agregar un registro en Visual Studio con un base Access, anteriormente solo declaraba la base de datos como Database y la Tabla como Recordset y al ingresar datos a la tabla solo ponía el signo ! después del nombre de tabla pero ahora el Visual Studio no me reconoce el signo ! y todo lo que he intentado reemplazar me lo rechaza diciendo que tiene la propiedad Read Only y no me permite recibir datos, un ejemplo del código es el siguiente:
NOMBRE4 = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory) & "\BASEFERIADOS.accdb"
conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & NOMBRE4
conexion.Open()
AUTORES.OpenRecordset("FERIADOS")

AUTORES.AddNew()
AUTORES!FERIADOS = TextBox56.Text

pd: Ya instalado todas las extensiones ADO, OLE y Jet que he encontrado

visual studio no te va a reconocer nada porque es una ide.. y aca lo importante no es la ide.. es el lenguaje.. y basicamente, no sabemos que lenguaje estas usando...

estoy utilizando Visual Basic en Visual Studio 2022

espera.. sera vb.net?? esa sintaxis que mostras es la que usabas antiguamente en vb o vba... puede ser???

exacto, estuve muchos años desactivado y estoy renovando un viejo proyecto en vb y algunos comandos ya no funcionan por la sintaxis, lo unico que necesito saber es que simbolo sustituyo al ! entre el nombre de tabla y el campo

Si es recordset puede ser collumn... deberias revisar la documentacion..

Muchas Gracias!
